# Spikes in latency in Kafka consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, benchmarking, latency

We are benchmarking Kafka on a LAN network consisting of three machines and a 1Gbps switch. Our simulation tool sends a specified number of messages per second at a given Mbps rate for a given period of time. Kafka runs with straight out-of-the-box default settings. We write to one node on one topic without partitioning.

Here is a screenshot from our Grafana dashboard showing the latency values in ms over the 5-minute run:

[image: ![Latency measured at consumer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQ5Py.png)]

This reveals an initial latency spike that may be due to connection establishment overhead or Kafka's buffering and batching techniques. However, we're unsure what causes a spike at the very end of the run. It is always present, but varies in amplitude between runs. What could be causing such a spike?

In the below graph, we use JMX metrics to calculate the rate of messages published by Kafka (green line) and we have a bespoke metric for the rate of messages consumed by our consumer:

[image]

(*) Latency is measured by inserting a timestamp in the Kafka message at the time of producing and simply subtracting it from the time of consuming at the receiver's end. Clocks were synchronized across the LAN for accurate measurement.

Comment: I suggest to check both broker and your apps for garbage collection pauses.